# Which wall is this?

Tags: italy, identify-this, architecture

I saw this lockscreen wallpaper in my windows 10 laptop.
Only thing i could understand was that this is in Rome, Italy.
No name was given with the info.

A google search on walls in Rome didn't provide any answers.

Can someone please help me understand which wall is this?

[image]

Comment: The ironic thing is that if you had hovered the mouse pointer over the `Like what you see` text at the top right, the computer would have told you where the image was taken.  (However this feature seems to come and go on my W10 laptop)

Comment: @Peter it said only Rome, and hence the question

Comment: @srk_cb  OK, but it wasn't clear to me if that was how you discerned that information.  I see aqueducts and I think Rome.

Comment: @Peter I have said "No name was given with the info"

Answer (score 4):

It is [Aqueduct Park in Rome, Italy](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowUserReviews-g187791-d2062465-r164292201-Parco_degli_Acquedotti-Rome_Lazio.html).